# WorkFlow Context System.NullReferenceException

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

in my workflow that insert or remove a contact form a Marketing list. According to an input  boolean parameter value. 
   True-> insert 
                -> IF contact exists
                               THEN return
                -> else
   False -> Remove 
                 -> IF don't exists 
                       THEN return

This WFA runs on incident.

On the first it fires, it works well, remove or add the contact. But I re-Run changing the Boolean value,  I get the following  exception Msg:

> Workflow paused due to error: Unhandled Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   ContactToMList.ContactToMList.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   executionContext)    at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>
> executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

It seems like does't take the context.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using System.Activities;
using ContactToMList;

namespace ContactToMList
{
   public class ContactToMList : CodeActivity
    {


        [Input("Contatto")]
        [ReferenceTarget("contact")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> contact { get; set; }

        [Input("Marketing List")]
        [ReferenceTarget("list")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> MList { get; set; }

        [Input("Inserimento")]
        public InArgument<bool> inserimento { get; set; }

        bool action = false;
        private static string _logs = string.Empty; 
        private static IOrganizationService myService = null;
        private static string _separataore = "\r\n"; 
        private static Log_Entity log = new Log_Entity(string.Empty, myService);
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            try
            {

                ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

                // Create the context
                IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();

                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();

                // Create the Organiztion service
                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
                myService = service;
                log.WriteLog("");
                // Get the target entity from the context
               // var target = context.InputParameters["EntityId"];


                Guid contactiId = contact.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext).Id;
                Guid ListId = MList.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext).Id;
                bool insert = inserimento.Get<bool>(executionContext);


                // Prepare DataContext by using AutoGenerated cs file
                XrmDataContext datacontext = new XrmDataContext(service);

                var MyContact = (from c in datacontext.ContactSet where c.ContactId == contactiId select c.Id).ToArray();
                var MyList = (from l in datacontext.ListSet where l.Id == ListId select l).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                // tutti i membri della lista di marketing
                var members = (from m in datacontext.ListMemberSet where m.ListId.Id == MyList.ListId select m.EntityId.Id).ToArray();


                if (MyList.MemberType == 2)
                {
                    if (MyList.Type.Value == false)
                    {
                        foreach (Guid id in members)
                            if (MyContact.FirstOrDefault() == id)
                                action = true;



                        if (insert && !action)
                        {

                            AddListMembersListRequest AddMemberRequest = new AddListMembersListRequest();

                            AddMemberRequest.ListId = ListId;
                            AddMemberRequest.MemberIds = MyContact;
                            // Use AddListMembersListReponse to get information about the request execution 
                            AddListMembersListResponse AddMemberResponse = service.Execute(AddMemberRequest) as AddListMembersListResponse;
                            //service.Update(MyList);

                        }
                        else if (!insert && action)
                        {

                            RemoveMemberListRequest RemoveMemberRequest = new RemoveMemberListRequest();
                            RemoveMemberRequest.ListId = ListId;
                            RemoveMemberRequest.EntityId = MyContact.FirstOrDefault();
                            // Use AddListMembersListReponse to get information about the request execution 
                            RemoveMemberListResponse RemoveMemberResponse = service.Execute(RemoveMemberRequest) as RemoveMemberListResponse;
                            // service.Update(MyList);

                        }
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        tracingService.Trace("Stai cercando di inserire un contatto in una lista di Marketing che non è statica.");
                        _logs += "Stai cercando di inserire un contatto in una lista di Marketing che non è statica." + _separataore;
                        return; 

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("Stai cercando di inserire un enittà diversa da un contatto.");
                    _logs += "Stai cercando di inserire un enittà diversa da un contatto." + _separataore;
                    return;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.WriteLog(ex.Message);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like a code error ;-)  Can you post the code?

Comment: Of Course.  I've posted it! :)

Comment: There are a lot of places this could be coming from.  Every time you use a Linq expression, you have assumed you will have a result; you then (after assuming you have a result) attempt to access members of the result.  This happens a few times in the code above.  The good news is, you can prove this true by debugging into the code.  Also, your code looks a lot like a question I'm answering in another thread

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question?  Yes, WF Activities and Plugins are different; and yes, WF is Async only.  On a personal note, I prefer Plugins for my business logic because I do not want them run ad-hoc, I do want them synchronous, and I want to be able to take advantage of entity images (sometimes).

Comment: The question is: CWF works are asynchronous and that's ok . So, I've tried to insert N contacts in the same time. But the result is that some contacts has been added and others not. Do you know how can I isolate every process?

Comment: I would have to debug your code to see what happens in the case of both a success and a failure.  Do you know how to make a console application using the CrmConnection to make calls to your Org Proxy?  I would try to convert this code to a Console application and then run it for both the success and failure case to see if I saw something different.  If this sounds like something you'd like to try but are not sure how to do, let me know.  Otherwise, I do not see anything stands out to me =/

Comment: Could give some input about how to make a console application using the CrmConnection to make calls to your Org Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

This is some code I use to interact with my Org Service Proxy.  I find it helpful for triggering plugins without going through the UI.  It's also helpful for cleaning up data I corrupt while developing plugins.

You need to populate your own Domain, Username, Password and Org Name.  The commented out code is something I was using to populate a succession of related entities.  Let me know if you need more help with this.

Where I have `TrainingContext`, you will replace this with the context you generate with the CrmSvcUtil from the CRM SDK.

```
CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=http://localhost/trainingorg1; Domain=; Username=; Password=;");
OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(connection);
string template = "http://localhost/main.aspx?etn={0}&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7B{1}%7D";

using (TrainingContext svc = new TrainingContext(service))
{
    svc.MergeOption = Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.MergeOption.NoTracking;

    training_customer customer = svc.training_customerSet.FirstOrDefault(c => c.training_name == "George.Lucas");
    customer.training_SocialSecurityNumber = "123-45-6789";
    svc.Update(customer);

            #region interaction activity
            //try
            //{
            //    training_customer customer = new training_customer
            //        {
            //            EmailAddress = "George.Lucas@Force.net",
            //            training_name = "George.Lucas",
            //            training_UniqueCustomerIdentifier = "George.Lucas"
            //        };
            //    customer.Id = svc.Create(customer);

            //    training_interactiontypemaster typeMaster = new training_interactiontypemaster
            //    {
            //        training_Description = "Indicates an Interaction initiated because a Customer needed to update an Address",
            //        training_InteractionTypeValue = "Address Update"
            //    };
            //    typeMaster.Id = svc.Create(typeMaster);

            //    training_interaction interaction = new training_interaction
            //    {
            //        training_name = "Command Prompt",
            //        training_Customer = customer.ToEntityReference(),
            //        training_Description = typeMaster.training_Description,
            //        training_InteractionType = typeMaster.ToEntityReference()
            //    };

            //    interaction.Id = svc.Create(interaction);
            //    EntityReference reference = interaction.ToEntityReference();
            //    customer.training_Interaction = reference;
            //    svc.Update(customer);

            //    training_interactionactivity activity = new training_interactionactivity
            //    {
            //        training_ActivityName = "Customer Update",
            //        training_Description = "Updating Customer: " + customer.training_name,
            //        training_Interaction = reference,
            //        training_Entity = string.Format(template, customer.LogicalName, customer.Id)
            //    };
            //    activity[customer.LogicalName] = customer.ToEntityReference();
            //    svc.Create(activity);

            //    training_address address = new training_address
            //    {
            //        training_City = "City",
            //        training_Country = "Country",
            //        training_County = "County",
            //        training_Interaction = reference,
            //        training_Street1 = "Street 1",
            //        training_Street2 = "Street 2"
            //    };
            //    address.Id = svc.Create(address);

            //    training_interactionactivity activityTwo = new training_interactionactivity
            //    {
            //        training_Address = address.ToEntityReference(),
            //        training_ActivityName = "Address Update",
            //        training_Description = "Updating the Address for Customer: " + customer.training_name,
            //        training_Interaction = reference,
            //        training_Entity = string.Format(template, address.LogicalName, address.Id)
            //    };
            //    //activityTwo[address.LogicalName] = new CrmEntityReference(training_address.EntityLogicalName, addressId);
            //    svc.Create(activityTwo);
            //}
            //catch (Exception e)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            //}
            #endregion
}
```